# How to build People photo gallery with messy style / disorder style thumnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, galleryview

I want to create a photo gallery like http://mormon.org/people/find/ . I want the messy style. could someone give me some idea any framework and plugin can do the job?

Comment: Also popularized by Apple's iPhoto and iPad photo viewer. This doesn't look too hard to do -- positions and scaling factors are probably randomized, and clicking on any picture swaps it smoothly with the one in the center.

Comment: they didn't randomize the positions and scaling if you refresh the page all the picture locations and size are at the same position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that page source, it looks like the plugin they are using is Jquery GalleryView, Found here http://plugins.jquery.com/project/galleryview

http://mormon.org/bc/assets/scripts/galleryview/jquery.galleryview.js

I wouldn't normally link to their source, but the site linked to at Jquery seems to bee down form the moment

Comment: Thanks Michael. Yes, it should take some function of galleryview plugin but it doesn't seem to have jquery in its source code.

Comment: Not directly but it looks like they included jQuery in their own file. mormonorg.min.js